# How To use Test in /dev/ folder?

Tags: unit-tests

Magento 1.9.x comes with a */dev/* folder (not meant to land in production!) containing many unit tests based on phpunit.

How can I use these tests and how to implement my own?

Answer (score 1):

The development documentation for the Magento Testing Framework (MTF) can be found here.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/mtf/mtf_introduction.html

The /dev/ folder was introduced in Magento CE 1.9.2. It should be deleted from live stores.

Comment: thx, can you add some practical example ... ( if not consider change your answer in a comment )